# After adding ELMAH and changing elmah.mvc.route the old route is still available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, routes, elmah

I've added ELMAH to my ASP.NET MVC 4 .Net 4 web application.

The intergration was simple and it works well.

I've changed the "elmah.mvc.route" value in the app settings of my web.config to an "Admin/SiteLog" route - the elmah log is displayed at this route now

But, it is also still shown at "/elmah" for some reason (with no css styling, but same content).

How can I disable the default elmah route?

The integration was made using [Elmah.MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) nuget package

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because the default route (assuming you have one) will still match to Elmah.Mvc.ElmahController.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

The "{controller}" portion of the route will find a matching controller whether you want it to or not. This is obviously problematic in this case.

You can add constraints on your routes by using IRouteConstraint, outlined [here](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx). The NotEqual constraint is actually pretty useful.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

public class NotEqual : IRouteConstraint
{
    private string _match = String.Empty;

    public NotEqual(string match)
    {
        _match = match;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return String.Compare(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match, true) != 0;
    }
}
```

So then exclude ElmahController from the default route by using the following.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = new NotEqual("Elmah") });
```

This will make requests for "/elmah" return a 404.

Answer (score 16):

I've just been working through this problem myself and the latest version seems to have a couple of app settings that works nicely enough for this.

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="true" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="admin/elmah" />
```

It's probably also worth being aware of the others so take a look after a default install.

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the location by updating the path in the `httpHandlers` section of the web.config

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="admin/elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't help, niether did changing all of the places that says "elmah.axd" in the web.config file

Comment: Try adding an IgnoreRoute in the RegisterRoutes method. This way, MVC will not try to handle the request:
routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/Elmah.axd"); 
routes.IgnoreRoute("admin/Elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: This patch will work, but I don't want a patch, I want to understand where it registers the default route and why it's stil there after my change in the web.config